# Pandas duplicated 3 fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/pr1/test/data.csv')
dupes = df[df.duplicated(subset=['state','county', 'name'], keep=False)]
dupes.to_csv('/pr1/test/duplicates.csv')
```

Dataframe:

```
state   county      name
MS      95          Woodland Heights
MS      105         Woodland Heights
VA      179         Woodlawn
VA      775         Woodlawn
VA      179         Woodlawn
VA      775         Woodlawn
```

Desired Output:

```
state   county      name
VA      179         Woodlawn
VA      775         Woodlawn
```

Current Output:

```
 state   county      name
```

Any thoughts on how to capture duplicate data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `keep=False` argument marks all duplicate rows across specified columns as `True`. If each row has a unique combination of `'state'`, `'county'` and `'name'`, then all rows will be marked `False`. See also [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

In other words, your result is empty because there are no duplicates across those 3 columns. You need to specify some logic which returns `True` values.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.